# Can AppDynamics work with a Prometheus backend?

Tags: influxdb, prometheus, appdynamics

Most popular logging and monitoring stacks like ELK stack or Time series DB-Grafana are designed to be integrated. Can AppDynamics work with other samplers/DBs, in particular Prometheus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are integration tools available between influxdb/AppDynamics and grafana/AppDynamics.

https://github.com/Appdynamics/MetricMover

https://grafana.com/plugins/dlopes7-appdynamics-datasource/installation).

There's nothing that integrates between Prometheus and AppDynamics at the moment

I'm not sure there will be one going forward, seeing how they are competing in the same space from different vantage points (Open Source vs Enterprise)